# Reduced group C*-algebra $C^*_r(\mathbb{Z}/2*\mathbb{Z}/2)$: norm of specific elements

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, geometric-group-theory

Consider the free product of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ with itself with generators
$$
\mathbb{Z}/2*\mathbb{Z}/2=\langle u,v\mid u^2=1=v^2\rangle
$$
and regard its group $C^*$-algebra
$$
C^*(\mathbb{Z}/2*\mathbb{Z}/2)=C^*_r(\mathbb{Z}/2*\mathbb{Z}/2)\subseteq B\Bigl(\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}/2*\mathbb{Z}/2)\Bigr).
$$

For $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, does someone know the norm of
$$
\lVert au+bv+1\rVert={?}
$$
(As another example I found that $\|au+bv\|=|a|+|b|$.)

In principle one should be able to compute the operator norm of this particular class of elements since they're given as concrete infinite dimensional matrices, but I couldn't figure out how.

Does someone have some idea perhaps?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer now, but the explicit isomorphism given in Theorem 1.3 of [the C*-algebra generated by two projections](https://www.mscand.dk/article/download/12283/10299) should allow you to calculate it very explicitly. This isomorphism identifies $C^*(\mathbb{Z}/2 \ast \mathbb{Z}/2)$ with the C*-subalgebra of $C([0,1],M_2(\mathbb{C}))$ given by those functions that are diagonal at the endpoints.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, that was precisely what we were looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: Where you wrote $\mathbb{Z}/2*\mathbb{Z}/2,$ might you have meant $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2 \text{?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I really mean the free product $\mathbb{Z}/2 * \mathbb{Z}/2$, so with non commuting generators.

Comment: This group is also called the infinite dihedral group and it is amenable, so reduced is not needed here. Moreover, the group was recently studied by Grigorchuk and Yang: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=tm&paperid=3797&option_lang=eng

Comment: @BorisBilich: Great, thank you for the reference!